# Using Excel VBA commands from within a Word VBA document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've having some difficulties with an odd error that seems to be random.

I have two Macro-Enabled documents, one Word and one Excel. The goal is to take user entered data from the Word document and then open and export that data to the next row of empty cells in the Excel document.

Naturally, I wanted to ensure that every time the Excel document is opened, no matter if it had been edited, the selected cell would always be in next available empty "A" Column Cell. To achieve this, I had a procedure upon opening the workbook to do just that.

The issue arises when randomly the VBA code is removed from the document. When the code is removed, the data obviously still gets exported but at whatever initial cell that was selected last.

I don't think the issue is the VBA code, but if anyone has any insight I would appreciate it.

Onto what I'm hoping will resolve the issue. I'm having difficulties and maybe it's not possible, but I want to be able to from within the Word VBA code, select that next empty "A" Column Cell before exporting the data over.

Here is the VBA for when the Excel Document is opened, which "resets" and gets the next available row ready to receive the data from the Word Document.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Here is the VBA for the Word Document to open the Excel Document and then export each data value to the cell in each column.

```vb
Set myxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxl.Visible = True
                            
Set exwb = myxl.workbooks.Open(exportPath)
                            
With exwb.Application
    .sheets("Sheet1").Select

    .activecell = arrayExportData(1)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(2)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(3)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(4)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(5)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(6)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(7)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(8)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(9)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(10)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(11)
    .activecell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    .activecell = arrayExportData(12)
    .activecell.Offset(1, -11).Range("A1").Select

    exwb.Save
    myxl.Quit
End With
```

Is there any way to have the Word Document within its VBA code achieve the same result as the Workbook_Open procedure? That way there wouldn't be any need for the Excel document to be in the XLSM format and the issue of the VBA being removed would be moot.

OR is there an issue with the Word VBA that might be contributing to the issues?

Thank you for any insight and assistance.

Comment: `OR is there an issue with the Word VBA that might be contributing to the issues` - [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683). Your Word code should locate the cell to use, not rely on it being activated when Excel file is opened. And after your Word code has located that cell, it should do `that_cell.Resize(, 12).Value = arrayExportData` instead of that wall of code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having trouble figuring out how to exactly to get the code to locate which cell to use. I went over the link you added for avoiding Select. When I tried testing your code with a defined Range that I set simply as 'rng = Range ("A2")' since I wanted the array data to test going into the A2 cell row. The debugger had a problem with using the '.Resize' method. So I'm not sure how to: 1. Find out the way to select the next empty "A" column cell available and 2. How to get the code you offered to send the array data to that row.

Comment: `Find out the way to select the next empty "A" column cell available` - by literally moving the code you have in the Excel file, `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select`, into the Word file. `How to get the code you offered to send the array data to that row` - I literally wrote that code in the comment, `hat_cell.Resize(, 12).Value = arrayExportData`, where `that_cell` is the next available cell in column A you have found.

Comment: I understand you provided the refined code for placing the array values into the row. I'm able to get the array exported by using `.activecell.Resize(,12).Value = arrayExportData` What I don't understand is how to reference and use the code from the Excel Open procedure to declare some range/variable that can replace the `.activecell` portion of the code to then put the data in the correct row. I assume that using `.activecell` is likely not preferred? I do apologize, my understanding of VBA is purely hobby-based, so I'm slow on the uptake.

Comment: When I move the code `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(x1Up).Offset(1,0).Select` into my word code it does not work and gives Error 1004.